# why is there an underlying line beneath my listView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, layout

I have the following xml's:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/errorMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/offers_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this xml for each item in the listView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/offerImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/lockImage"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/lock_closed" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp" >


        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/unlikeBtn"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#334455"
            android:text="@string/unlike" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And i cannot understand why i see an underlying line below the list?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is listview divider and below code to remove this:-

do in you code

```
getListView().setDivider(null);
getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
```

or do on xml

```
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:divider="#00000000" (as transparent color)
```

Comment: isn't one of the properties enough? @null 0dp or #000000 ?

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have single row in listview and it is the divider line between 2 rows .
You can remove it by using 
**android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:divider="#00000000"**